# How Use Authentication and Authoriziation of my IdentityServer with itself?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an Api with Name MyApi and I use another asp.net core application with Identityserver4 for Protect MyApi,Now I don't have any problem in MyApi but,I want to save my Users's `NationalCode` ,So I should save this in my IdentityServer Database,But can't Get UserId (with User.Identity.Name) in my IdentityServer Project,I had same problem in my previose question

[User.Identity.Name is null in my ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278327/user-identity-name-is-null-in-my-asp-net-core-web-api)

Now I have this problem in my IdentityServer4 project,So

Can I use Of MyApi token Or I should get a new token for send request to my idenittyserver4 project?

If I can MyAPI token ,How should I add configuration to solve the problem?

If I should take new token for my IdentityServer4 project,DO I need to want users to login again?!!!

**Edit**

I found a tutorail in below link but My Problem not solved Yet.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html

I have seed my IdentityDatabase with below method

```
public async Task AddIdenityServerApiToResources(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
                var ccontext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
                ccontext.Database.Migrate();
                //=============================================================
                ccontext.ApiResources.Add(new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName) {
                    UserClaims =
                    {
                        JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                    }
                }.ToEntity());
                //Add ApiResource To Client's Scope
                var Clients = ccontext.Clients.Include(e => e.AllowedScopes);
                foreach (var item in Clients)
                {
                    item.AllowedScopes.Add(new IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.ClientScope() { Scope = IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName });
                }
                var Count = await ccontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                if (Count > 0)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I'm experiencing the same issue here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with below link:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html

But the problem was where that I don't used `Authorize` on my controller with `LocalApi.PolicyName` policy

```
[Route("localApi")]
[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
public class LocalApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

after that the prolem was solvled

Answer (score 2):

In IdentityServer4 startup.cs ConfigureServices

You should treat the api as if it's like any other api that needs to be secured by idserver4.

meaning: use AddAuthentication and AddJWTToken:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https:// idserver4 ";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.Audience = "api name";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
```

in API controller :

use Authorize Attirbute and determine the authentication scheme like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: ,Your Solution didn't help me

Comment: I don't need just Authorization,I need to get UserId(Authentication)

Comment: I used http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html tutorial but it doesn't help too.User.Idenitty.Name is null

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem thanks to [@mohsen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61440259/10654562) and [@WeB answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448440/10654562).

Specify Policy name in `Authorize` attribute and use `AddMvc()` instead of `AddMvcCore()` or `AddControllersWithViews()` methods in `Program.cs`